# Evaluate a Pig string field to grouped numeric array?

Tags: apache-pig, user-defined-functions

Using **Pig 0.8.1** and the data structure/format available to me, is there a feasible way (with a UDF or preferably native) to convert a field in Pig/Hadoop to a grouped tuple? I have a list of foreign IDs that I can potentially map to and replace with more descriptive text if I can split/eval the data.

**Example:**

```
| TYPE      | JOINED IDS | ...
| some text | []         | ...
| more text | [123]      | ...
| even more | [123,456]  | ...
```

If I am able to take field2 and [somehow] break it out, I think I should be able to use a JOIN against a look-up table. If my look-up table is structured like so. . .

```
| ID  | DESCRIPTION |
| 123 | foo         |
| 456 | bar         |
```

I would like to return my values something close to:

```
| TYPE      | JOINED IDS | JOINED TEXT | ...
| some text | []         | []          | ...
| more text | [123]      | [foo]       | ...
| even more | [123,456]  | [foo,bar]   | ...
```

I've briefly looked into `TOKENIZE`, and with a bit of regex replacements (i.e. using an existing UDF) convert the text to a tuple, but I don't know if this is the best approach and if this is even what I would want to do in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide the output of `DESCRIBE` for both of the inputs you want to do the JOIN on?  The answer will vary greatly depending on the schema.

Comment: The data types? Assume all fields are CHARARRAY. ID may be INT.

Comment: My value under the `JOINED IDS` field is a literal "`[123,456]`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, what you need to do is make a copy of `JOINED_IDS` which is a bag, then `FLATTEN` it. After it is `FLATTEN`ed then you can do a join with the lookup table by `ID`. Then group on `JOINED_IDS` and `TYPE`. This can be done like:

**NOTE:** The UDF is only necessary to convert `JOINED_IDS` into a bag.

**myudf.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

@outputSchema('tokens:{(token:chararray)}')
def tokenize_string(s):
    split_s = s.strip('[]').split(',')
    return split_s
```

**myscript.pig**

```
REGISTER myudf.py USING jython AS myudf ;

-- A has the schema (TYPE: chararray, JOINED_IDS: chararray)
B = FOREACH A GENERATE *, FLATTEN(myudf.tokenize_string(JOINED_IDS)) ;

-- look_up has the schema (ID: chararray, DESCRIPTION: chararray)
C = JOIN B BY token LEFT, look_up BY ID ;

D = GROUP C BY (TYPE, JOINED_IDS) ;

E = FOREACH D GENERATE FLATTEN(group), C.DESCRIPTION AS JOINED TEXT ;
```

Schema and output of `E`:

```
E: {group::B::TYPE: chararray,group::B::JOINED_IDS: chararray,JOINED TEXT: {(look_up::DESCRIPTION: chararray)}}
(even_more,[123,456],{(foo),(bar)})
(more_text,[123],{(foo)})
(some_text,[],{()})
```

If you need `JOINED_TEXT` to be in the same format as `JOINED_IDS` you can use this UDF:

```
@outputSchema('JOINED_TEXT: chararray')
def stringify(BAG):
    if BAG[0][0] is None:
        return '[]'
    return '[%s]' % ','.join(BAG)
```

Schema and output when using `stringify`:

```
E: {group::B::TYPE: chararray,group::B::JOINED_IDS: chararray,JOINED_TEXT: chararray}
(even_more,[123,456],[foo,bar])
(more_text,[123],[foo])
(some_text,[],[])
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll be working on this today, so I'll post another comment if I have any problems.

Comment: I do seem to be having issues with the `@outputSchema('tokens:{(token:chararray)}')` line, but after getting Jython downloaded and referenced, the rest is working well so far.
    `Error parsing schema for script function from the decorator org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "{" "{ "" at line 1, column 8.
Was expecting one of:
    "int" ...
    "long" ...
    "float" ...
    "double" ...
    "chararray" ...
    "bytearray" ...
    "int" ...
    "long" ...
    "float" ...
    "double" ...
    "chararray" ...
    "bytearray" ...`

Comment: Wait, so after you got Jython working did it keep on giving you that error?

Comment: This was after I was able to get Jython working. I know that it's working because it wouldn't otherwise be able to run the script, much less return an error. I did come across this, if it's any consolation: [Unresolved Pig Improvement](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1942)

Comment: My backup plan should this fail, I can always send the field to the UDF and let it do all of the work. My lookup table I can either grab via MySQL or the output file that I send it to (in prep for this step). Not a perfect solution, but I can if necessary.

Comment: One more thing. . . In this `0.8.1` version, I've tried combinations for `@outputSchema('tokens:{(token:chararray)}')` such as `tokens:bag{(token:chararray)}`, `tokens:{t:(token:chararray)}`, `tokens:bag{t:(token:chararray)}`, `tokens:tuple{(token:chararray)}`, `tokens:bag{t:tuple(token:chararray)}`

Comment: Maybe the return for the first UDF should be `return [ (s,) for s in split_s ]` ? Since it really wants to it to be a list of tuples?

Comment: Honestly, I know nothing about creating Pig UDFs, and I'm new to Python decorators (makes sense though). I'll try that.

Comment: I'm still not getting this to work. I've tried a lot of combos, but I'm getting errors that read `ERROR 1070: Could not resolve pythonudfs.tokenize_string using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]`.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/udf.html#Python+UDFs). Are you following everything for it?  The error is indicating that maybe something is wrong with how you are registering the script. `tokenize_string` can be rewritten as pure Pig, but `stringify` can not. If you are still having issues I'll post the pure Pig version of `tokenize_string`.

Comment: Ignore what I had said before. I just realized that I had renamed the function, duh!

Comment: Ha! Don't worry it happens to the best of us. :) Everything works now?

Comment: Not yet. . . Your `@outputSchema('tokens:{(token:chararray)}')` code still isn't working, and if I change the schema at all, then it makes it react differently in Pig. I've tried: `@outputSchema("tokens:bag{t:tuple(token:chararray)}")`, `@outputSchema("tokens:tuple(token:chararray)")` and `@outputSchema("tokens:bag{t:(token:chararray)}")`, with the following types of outputs: `return split_s`, `return tuple(split_s)` and `return [(s,) for s in split_s]`. Much appreciative of your in-depth help and patience!

Comment: Hey, the automatic 'take to chat' message hasn't been tripped yet, so I've created a room (since it is really more suitable).  Here is a [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37058/discussion-between-mr2ert-and-j-law).